# Finding arc length with y(t) = integral of 0 to X

Tags: integration, radicals

**Find the length of the curve**

$$y=\int_0^x \sqrt{(1+t^2)^2-1}dt$$
$$0\le x \le 2$$

Studying for an exam with sample finals, and I came across this problem. I know the formula for arc lengths in polar coordinates, so I surmise that $r=1+t^2$
, which I suppose means $\frac{dr}{d\theta}=-1$, but that's as far as I can figure this out, and I'm not even sure of that part. How do I grok this?

Comment: Corrected! Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for arc length is given by
$$L = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \, dx$$
so it's worth trying what happens when you evaluate this.
First, consider what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ should be. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, you can see that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{(1+x^2)^2 - 1}$, so $\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}=1+x^2$. From here, the arc length integral should be easier to evaluate.

Comment: It absolutely was! Thanks a bunch, B. Mehta!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general we can write, if:

$$\text{y}_{\space\text{n}}\left(x\right):=\int_\text{n}^x\text{f}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\tag1$$

We get, for the arclength:

$$\mathscr{S}\left(\text{a},\text{b}\right)=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}\text{y}_{\space\text{n}}\left(x\right)}{\text{d}x}\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\sqrt{1+\text{f}\left(x\right)^2}\space\text{d}x\tag2$$

So, in your example:

$$\mathscr{S}\left(0,2\right)=\int_0^2\sqrt{1+\left(\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)^2-1}\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\int_0^2\left(1+x^2\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{14}{3}\tag3$$